# Susy "no-gutter" doesnt work

Tags: css, susy

i try out susy and my first problems starts ;) at first i try to remove the gutter from an element with

```
@include span(no-gutters);
```

this are my settings

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    gutters: 10,
    global-box-sizing: border-box,
    math: fluid,
    gutter-position: inside,
    debug: (
        image: show
    )
);
```

is this the correct way?

the mixin with "full" works just fine

```
@include span(full);
```

i found this at the docs
http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#span-mixin
scroll down to "Other Settings"

> Use no-gutters to remove gutter output from an individual span, ...

a short codepen, maybe i'm doing at some other place something wrong ;)
http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/KVVWgL?editors=110

gregor ;)

Comment: hmm or should i just use   padding:0 instead?

Comment: i played a little bit more around and this also works @include gutters(0px);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `no-gutters` key word does not *remove existing* gutters (maybe the docs should be more clear). It just keeps the `span` mixin from *outputting new* gutters. It removes the gutter-output, but it doesn't override gutters set somewhere else. To do that, `gutters(0px)` is a fine solution, as you found above.